# How is it possible to run a code only 1 time?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, c#-5.0

I want the MessageBox in this code to be run only 1 time. I want it to be shown only one time. How can I do it?

```
    if(textBox1.Text != "")
    
    {
     listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
        
        textBox1.Clear();
    }
    
    else
    {
      DialogResult click = MessageBox.Show("Info Screen", "TextBox is Empty. Do you want to add a 
  blank space?", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
    
    if(click==DialogResult.OK)
    
    {
    
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
    
    }
    
    }
```

Comment: You can add a `bool _messageBoxShown;` to your class, set it to true after the first time and check it before displaying the message box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a boolean and use an if statement and inside that if statement make the boolean false and show your message box

```
bool boolMessage = true;

if(boolMessage == true)
{
MessageBox.Show("One time");
boolMessage = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable of type boolean and save the mark if the message has been shown. Then in your code add

Global:
bool isFirstTime = true;

In your code:

```
if (isFirstTime) {
      DialogResult click = MessageBox.Show("Info Screen", "TextBox is Empty. Do you want to add a 
  blank space?", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);

      isFirstTime = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think adding a boolean flag in your case is just code pollution. You can solve this problem the other way. => When do you want the MessageBox to be displayed? When the textbox content equals `""` and you want this to run only once. Why not to check if there is already an `""` within the listbox before displaying the messagebox? Something like this:

```
else
{
   if(listbox1.Items.IndexOf("") > -1)
      return;

   // continue with displaying the messagebox
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a boolean and use an if to make sure that the code runs only if the Boolean is true, then, inside the if just set the Boolean to false.

You can try also using a function and calling it once.

I am not sure if I answered your question.